# Is there a way to enable "beats audio" from within Linux?

Tags: sound, hp

I got HP Pavilion dv6 7010ej, using beats audio, how can i enable full audio model support on it (including subwoofer etc.)?

Sound Card:
lspci says:
Audio device: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04).
Windows says: "IDT HD Audio".

Comment: What is your audio card? If you don't know, type into the terminal: 'lspci' and look for audio.

Answer (score 6):

See my post on Reddit here:

http://www.reddit.com/r/linux/comments/17sov5/howto_beats_audio_hp_laptop_speakers_on/

The model=ref method doesn't work quite right, at least not on my laptop.  You have to remap some HD audio ports that appear disconnected and then all the speakers work.  There's a convenient little tool out there that does just that.  I also got it working under Debian and it works without breaking headphones too.

> Step 1: Install hda-jack-retask from here:
> [https://launchpad.net/~diwic/+archive/hda](https://launchpad.net/%7Ediwic/+archive/hda) (ppa:diwic/hda)
>
> Step 2: Open
> hda-jack-retask
>
> Step 3: Select the IDT 92HD91BXX codec (may be
> different on other models)
>
> Step 4: Check the "Show unconnected pins"
> box (the internal speakers do not show as connected)
>
> Step 5: Remap
> 0x0d (Internal Speaker, Front side) to "Internal speaker"
>
> Step 6:
> Remap 0x0f ("Not connected" but is the under-display speakers) to
> "Internal speaker"
>
> Step 7: Remap 0x10 ("Not connected" but is the
> subwoofer) to "Internal speaker (LFE)"
>
> Step 8: Apply now, then test
> with your favorite audio program (some may not work due to Pulse
> reset, so find one that does, verify sound is coming from all
> speakers).
>
> Step 9: If it works, select "Install boot override" to save
> the settings to apply at boot time.
>
> Step 10: Reboot. When it comes
> back, you should have full sound from all speakers. Also test
> headphones. Plugging in headphones should disable sound from all
> internal speakers.
>
> From Ubuntu 13.10, hda-jack-retask is part of alsa-tools. Just install
> the alsa-tools-gui package from the regular archive and start
> "hdajackretask".

Comment: This should be accepted as the correct answer IMO. I'd used the model=ref method too and had the same headphone problems. This cleared it up perfectly. Thank you!

Comment: However, please put at least the actionable summary text of your entry here - linking to external sites for answers is a great way to make this place into a ghost town when those external sites disappear.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me on Linux Mint, I found it on an HP forum.

Run this command to edit the alsa-base.conf file:

`sudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf`

Now you need to add this line to the file (as shown in the picture):

`options snd-hda-intel model=ref`

[image]

Now restart your computer for the changes to take effect. This worked for me on 11.04 (Natty Narwhal).

Answer (score 1):

This was done in my own HP envy and this process works on all HP laptops containing beats audio.

STEP 1

Install hda-jack-retask from https://launchpad.net/~diwic/+archive/hda . Download this small application according to your version of Ubuntu. After the completion of download, install the app.

STEP 2

After the app is installed, go to the terminal and type hda-jack-retask which opens the file. Open app using terminal

STEP 3

At the top, in codec section, select IDT 92HD91BXX codec.

This code varies with various models. Check it

STEP 4

Check the “ Show unconnected pins” at the right side.

STEP 5

After this, you will see different types of unconnected pins of your sound driver. You have to map these pins to the right part of the beats audio drive. Care must be taken at this point.

You can see there are various types of pins. We are not aware about these things. Even I don’t know

what I am doing and is confusing. BUT do not worry at all.

You just have to play on three pins. They are 0x0d , 0x0f and 0×10.

STEP 6

Go to the section having pin id : 0x0d .

Change (Internal Speaker, Front side) to “Internal speaker”.

STEP 7

Go to the section having pin id: 0x0f.

Change (Not connected) to “Internal speaker”. This part is about the under-display speakers.

STEP 8

Go to the section having pin id: 0×10.

Change (Not connected) to “Internal speaker (LFE)”. This part is about the sub-woofer.

STEP 9

You are finally done with those pin settings. Apply it now. You can test with some sound. Check whether all the speakers are producing desired sound. The settings must be done as in following picture.

Do as it is

STEP 10

If everything is all right, install boot override from the bottom right side and restart your device.

Finally you must have sound with beats audio. Enjoy the sound and music. Also plug in the headphones, it must disable the external sound when the headphone is plugged in.

you can visit here for more information. http://www.chromeearth.com/enable-beats-audio-in-ubuntu/

Comment: Does this still apply? I am running ubuntu 14.04 on  hp envy-15-j19nf, but WHATERVER i connect (0x0e -> 0x10) to internal/LFE/back... ANY configuration is same. I think all spakers are active at once, the configuration does not make difference (except if i set every output to "not connected"

http://icecat.us/en/p/hp/k4d07ea/notebooks-0888793725931-15-j192nf-24682973.html