# B&O laptop speaker's driver in hp laptop

Tags: drivers, sound, hp

Now a days Hp is using [B&O speaker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bang_%26_Olufsen) for it's laptop. I am using 15 ab523tx model. Is there any open source driver or any support from ubuntu?

Comment: Are you saying there is no sound or there is sound but you want extra tweaking options specific to the `HP 15-ab523tx`? This link might be helpful: http://askubuntu.com/questions/302340/is-there-a-way-to-enable-beats-audio-from-within-linux

Comment: No, sound is there but not good as  in windows with driver provided by hp. Volume is low.

Comment: The link I provided discusses how to turn on sub-woofer for HP and might contain helpful hints for you too.

Comment: I am facing the same issue to and no solution so far